# How does the convolution filter work in StatsModels seasonal.seasonal_decompose?

Tags: python, convolution, statsmodels

I am using [`seasonal.seasonal_decompose`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html), for 1D array time series with length N.
I am searching for seasonality with time period `2l`.

Now my question is how does convolution filter work in this code? Does it make a matrix with of `2l*(N/2l)` dimension and then work with that network?
Which type of convolution filter does it use? CNN?

I want to know the story of the mathematics behind the convolution filter used in this code.

Answer (score 1):

It uses [scipy *convolve*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) filter.
here is the [seasonal_decompose source code](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.html#seasonal_decompose) extract:

```
def seasonal_decompose(x, model="additive", filt=None, period=None, two_sided=True,)
...
    if filt is None:
    if period % 2 == 0:  # split weights at ends
        filt = np.array([0.5] + [1] * (period - 1) + [0.5]) / period
    else:
        filt = np.repeat(1.0 / period, period)

    nsides = int(two_sided) + 1
    trend = convolution_filter(x, filt, nsides)
...
from scipy import signal
def convolution_filter(x, filt, nsides=2):
    ...
    result = signal.convolve(x, filt, mode='valid')
    ...
    return PandasWrapper.wrap(result)
```

where ***convolution filter*** is basically a wrapper of scipy.signal.convolve function.
As I understood from [scipy.signal.convolve source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.0/scipy/signal/_signaltools.py#L1294-L1414) it uses either direct convolve of fft convolve transform.
To learn more about convolution, proceed to [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)

Short summary from wiki:

> Convolution is defined as the integral of the product of the two functions after one is reversed and shifted

and here the second function (*filt*) is constant by default.